# Inserting a component name as a variable string

Tags: reactjs, escaping, jsx

In my data I have a field that contains a value which is "TableTwoColum". "TableTwoColum" is the name of a component that I wish to call in the parent component. The variable seems to be rendering as text on the page rather than the html code.

CODE

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
// import TableTwoColum from '../molecules/table-two-column';
import Test from '../molecules/test-component'



export default function(props) {
  const ComponentName = props.data[0].tableType;
  const componentString = "<"+ ComponentName +"bookFormat={props.bookFormat} data={props.data}"

  return (
    <section id={props.sectionName} className={'padding-3 page-size-'+props.bookFormat}>
    {props.data[0].article}
    {componentString}       

  </section>
  );
}
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
// import TableTwoColum from '../molecules/table-two-column';
import Test from '../molecules/test-component'



export default function(props) {
  const ComponentName = props.data[0].tableType;
  const componentString = "<"+ ComponentName +"bookFormat={props.bookFormat} data={props.data}"

  return (
    <section id={props.sectionName} className={'padding-3 page-size-'+props.bookFormat}>
    {props.data[0].article}
    {componentString}       

  </section>
  );
}
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED
I have tried 
``
const componentString = {"<"+ ComponentName +"bookFormat={props.bookFormat} data={props.data}"}

```
this does not compile "ine 9:30:  Parsing error: Unexpected token"
```

const componentString = ("<"+ ComponentName +"bookFormat={props.bookFormat} data={props.data}")

```
this still escapes as text
```

Comment: Thats not a valid JSX.. You need to use conditional rendering

Comment: Yes the JSX is not valid and also if you want to keep jsx in a string, the you can use <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: YOUR_STRING }} />

Comment: I get that I'm doing something wrong but I don;t understand from these answer what the correct approach is to change the sub component that is called by props

Comment: I want to conditionally call a different component based on the data in the props